# Is there a way to tell which parameters in an AWS parameters group have been changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-aurora

I'm hoping there is a general way, though I'm specifically looking at an instance of Aurora PostgreSQL that I know I've adjusted one or two parameters for. However, there are **nineteen pages** of settings and there is no "default value" column or "last modified" column or list of events to help me determine which parameters I've changed.

[image]